# How to set a custom font-face in a WebView loaded with a URL

Tags: android, css, kotlin, webview

I am trying to load a website with a url and change the font from the app's asset folder.

I have created a CSS file in assets folder `assets/style.css`

```css
@font-face { font-family: "my_font"; src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/my_custom_font.ttf"); } body {font-family: "my_font";}
```

Then I inject the css to the webView like this.

```kotlin
webView?.let {
    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    settings.useWideViewPort = true
    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            val style = assets.open("style.css").bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
            val js = """
                 var style = document.createElement('style');
                 style.type = 'text/css';
                 style.innerHTML = '$style';
                 document.head.appendChild(style);
            """.trimIndent()
            evaluateJavascript(js) {}
        }
    }
    loadUrl("https://somedomain.com")
}
```

If I only manipulate styling such as font-size or radius, it works. But if I define a font-face then use that in the body as a font-family it does not work. The font changes in the UI but not to the font I'm trying to set(falls back to some default font i guess).
I have also tried to use `WebViewAssetLoader` and override the `shouldInterceptRequest` function but it didn't work either.

*Note that*

- I don't have the html content so I cannot use `loadDataWithBaseUrl()`
- I don't have access to the content of the CSS returned from the server, i cannot ask owner to add my font-face to the CSS
- It needs to be this custom font from the asset folder (or res/raw folder if it helps)